# Create a new and custom collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

In my app im getting a array of objects, from the table, and in the table i get the information regarding each object, but i need to create a new collection with specific name properties but with the values from the collection i went and get.
How can i create a new custom collection from the old one i got from DB?

my code:

```
$conditions = collect($user->conditions()
->withTrashed()
->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
->get());
```

Example of how i was trying do do:

```
$newCollection =  $conditions->map(function ($condition) {
           unset($condition['condition_privacy']);
           unset($condition['condition_privacy_id']);
           unset($condition['discount_type']);
           unset($condition['id']);
           unset($condition['condition_privacy']);
           unset($condition['proponent']);
           unset($condition['simplified_laboratory']);
           unset($condition['simplified_laboratory_id']);
           $condition['new_property'] = 'some data';
            return $condition;
        });
```

But this way above is not quite good, i prefer in instead removing the properties from the original, i wish to create a new collection with new properties and getting values from the old collections.

note:
Im using laravel 5.1.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Check this link to see what you can do with collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#available-methods

Comment: i just updated my question

Comment: to remove fields you can use `select('column1', 'column2')` method when retrieving data to get only given fields

Comment: You all set here?